# Take string from input and make an AJAX request in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my code :

http://jsfiddle.net/n8t2born/1/

there are 3 js files , and it works pretty much good when I use static URL (without `inputCity` variable inside) . How should I tell angular correctly to take that info from my input and put it into the link and show weather info for a particular city ?

This is my form:

```
    <form class="form-container" ng-submit="Weather.getWeather(inputCity)">
        <input class="input-field" type="text" ng-model="inputCity" placeholder="City">
        <input class="button-style" type="submit" value="Show Weather">
    </form>
```

and it is my angular.factory:

```
angular
.module('weather.factory', [])
.factory('Weather', [
    '$http',
    function($http) {
        return {
            getWeather : function(inputCity) {
                return $http({
                    url: 'http://api.wunderground.com/api/KEY/conditions/q/' + inputCity + '.json',
                    method: 'GET'
                })
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

Comment: The way this question is written, it is likely to attract downvotes and/or close votes.  In order for a question to be on topic for the site, you need to provide a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example *in the question itself*.  see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and [ask]

Comment: and got an answer, instead of a closure :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never call you service method from your controller which has promise, It should call from controller & then update you required location data in ajax sucess

**HTML**

```
<form class="form-container" ng-submit="submitForm(inputCity)">
    <input class="input-field" type="text" ng-model="inputCity" placeholder="City">
    <input class="button-style" type="submit" value="Show Weather">
</form>
```

**Code**

```
$scope.submitForm =function(inputCity){
   Weather.getWeather(inputCity).success(function(){
      //data updation will lie here
   }).error(function(error){
      //do error handling here
   })
};
```